# What is the proof of this Hermitian matrix property in Linear discriminant analysis?

Tags: matrices, discriminant

SORRY FOR POORLY FRAMED QUESTION. JUST SIGNED UP HERE. THANK YOU.

I am trying to derive the discriminant function for a problem given in Pattern Recognition. I am stuck at following step:

$$x^{T}\Sigma_{i}^{-1}\mu_{i}=\mu_{i}^{T}\Sigma_{i}^{-1}x$$

I found this equation on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis#LDA_for_two_classes) wikipedia page on Linear dicriminant analysis. It says that the equation is valid as the $Σ_i$ matrix is Hermitian. How do I prove this?

Comment: External references should placed in the body of the question, if possible. It will help you get good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author has used "Hermitian" when "symmetric" is more appropriate.  The equation doesn't use the Hermitian transpose, so it wouldn't be correct as written for complex vectors/matrices.  Normally, the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ would be real, so I'll proceed by assuming that everything in the equation is real.

The quantity on the left hand side of the equation is a scalar, so it is equal to its transpose.

$x^{T}\Sigma_{i}^{-1}\mu_{i} = (x^{T}\Sigma_{i}^{-1}\mu_{i})^{T}$

The transpose of the product is the product of the transposes in reverse order.

$ (x^{T}\Sigma_{i}^{-1}\mu_{i})^{T} = \mu_{i}^{T}\Sigma_{i}^{-T}x$

Since $\Sigma_{i}^{-1}$ is symmetric, $\Sigma_{i}^{-T}=\Sigma_{i}^{-1}$, and

$x^{T}\Sigma_{i}^{-1}\mu_{i} = \mu_{i}^{T}\Sigma_{i}^{-1}x$